# Not able to use asciimath using AsciidoctorJ

Tags: asciidoctor, asciimath

I am trying to convert a asciidoc file containing math expression to html using AsciidoctorJ, but have been unsuccessful so far.

This is the math.asciidoc that i am trying to convert.

```
= My Diabolical Mathmatical Opus
Jamie Moriarty

sample1

asciimath:[sqrt(4) = 2] 
stem:[sqrt(4) = 2]
```

I am using the below configuration in Asciidoc

```
Attributes attributes = AttributesBuilder.attributes()
            .math("asciimath")
            .get();

Options options = OptionsBuilder.options()
            .attributes(attributes)
            .docType("article")
            .safe(SafeMode.SERVER)
            .backend("html5")
            .get();

asciidoctor.convert(asciiDoc, options);
```

The output always shows something like this:

```
sample1

\$sqrt(4) = 2\$
\$sqrt(4) = 2\$
```

In the above generated HTML output, how do we render the mathematical equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asciidoctor support asciimath and latexmath syntax and the output produced by asciimath can be rendered on browser using http://asciimath.org js library (other asciimath libraries can also be used).

Asciidoctorj uses `\$` as the delimiter for **asciimath** markup, so we need to configure MathJax using the following configuration:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
       asciimath2jax: {
           delimiters: [['\\$','\\$'], ['`','`']]
       }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
...
</head>
//rest of html
</html>
```

After we include the above code snippet in `<head>` section of html, *asciimath* rendering shall work fine.

We can refer to this section of Asciidoctor documents for activating support of asciimath inside asciidocs: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#activating-stem-support